# Method doesn't exist setToaddress issue

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, send-email, set

I have below class where I am getting error :

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddresses(String)

**Apex class**

```
public class MailerUtils {

    public static void sendMail(string message , String Accname , string AccLName , String AddLine1 , String CName , String ProdName , String Quan) {
String sendtoemail ;
String[] sendtoemailarray;
List<string> sendto;

//String userEmail = i.Owner.email; 
List<ABV_Form_Request_abv__c>  ACS= [select Email_abv__c, User_ID_abv__c from ABV_Form_Request_abv__c where User_ID_abv__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
if(!ACS.isEmpty()){
   sendtoemail  = ACS[0].Email_abv__c;
    sendtoemailarray= sendtoemail.split(';');
}
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = 
  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 
        for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     

            addresses.add( u.Email);

        }
         EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id,htmlValue,Body from EmailTemplate where name = : message];
         String htmlbody= templateID.htmlvalue;
         System.debug('Accname @'+Accname);
         htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}', Accname +' ' + AccLName);
htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Address_abv__r.Name}', AddLine1); //
htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Campaign_Name__c}', CName);
htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Product_Name_abv__c}', ProdName);
htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Requested_Quantity_abv__c}', Quan);

        email.setToAddresses(sendtoemailarray);
        email.setHtmlBody(htmlbody);
        //email.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        email.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
        email.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserID());
        /*List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
      ccTo.add(userEmail);*/
        email.setCcAddresses(addresses);
       // email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
        email.setToAddresses(sendtoemail);
       // email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');
        mails.add(email);
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

    }   

   /* public static testMethod void testSendMail() {
        sendMail('This is my email message');
    }*/

}
```

Comment: Is this still an outstanding question?

Answer (score 2):

See: [SingleEmailMessage Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm). Instead of passing `String`, you need to pass `List<String>`.

```
email.setToAddresses(new List<String> {sendToEmail});
```

> **setToAddresses(toAddresses)**
>
> Optional. A *list* of email addresses to which you are sending the email. The maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100. This argument is allowed only when a template is not used.
>   Signature
>
> public Void setToAddresses(String[] toAddresses)
>
> **Parameters**
>   toAddresses
>   Type: *String[]*
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Void
>
> **Usage**
>
> All emails must have a recipient value in at least one of the following fields:
>
> - toAddresses
> - ccAddresses
> - bccAddresses
> - targetObjectId

Comment: don't you want `{..}` instead of `(..)` in the instantiation of the list? `sendToEmail` is a scalar, not a list

Comment: @crop1645 Good catch! Fixed.